# How to add same save method to all models

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I have the following model:

```
class Series(models.Model):
    item_id = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=600, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(self.__class__, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if not self.item_id:
            self.item_id = '%s%s' % (self.__class__.__name__[0], self.pk)
            self.save()
```

I've created this generic save method that I'd like to apply to other models as well. How would I do this in the `models.py` file?

Comment: Create a mixin class containing the save method, and for each model extends it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 options (both are pretty similar, they vary in a subtle way):

1. Create a parent class:

   ```
   class MyModel(models.Model):
       """My Custom Model Class"""
       def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
           super(self.__class__, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
           if not self.item_id:
               self.item_id = '%s%s' % (self.__class__.__name__[0], self.pk)
               self.save()
       # Must make the parent Model abstract to avoid table creation
       class Meta:
           abstract = True

   class Series(MyModel):
       item_id = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True, blank=True)
       name = models.CharField(max_length=600, blank=True)
   ```
2. Create a Mixin

   ```
   class MySaveMixin(object):
       """My Mixin for providing save functionality to Models"""
       def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
           super(self.__class__, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
           if not self.item_id:
               self.item_id = '%s%s' % (self.__class__.__name__[0], self.pk)
               self.save()

   class Series(models.Model, MySaveMixin):
       item_id = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True, blank=True)
       name = models.CharField(max_length=600, blank=True)
   ```

Comment: You must make the parent class abstract, otherwise you'll end up with a horrible multi-table inheritance scenario.